# NVIDIA GPU in VM VirtualBox how to make it work?

Tags: ubuntu, server, operating-system, backend, virtual-machine

I need to setup server with GPU. I can't afford to rent a dedicated server so i decided to make it with VM on my desktop pc. But I encountered a problem: VirtualBox does not use my video card (NVIDIA RTX 3060), since it is already used in the main system. Are there any ways to run VirtualBox (or another VM) so that the server runs using the video card and the main system can be used?

Installing two parallel OS is not an option